# Grab Number using Preg_Match

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = 'title="room 5 stars"';
preg_match_all('/title="([0-9]+)"/sm', $str, $rate);
```

I need to grab number 5 from title. The regex doesn't work!

If i do this:

```
preg_match_all('/title="([0-9]+)"/sm', $str, $rate);
```

I get:

```
room 5 stars
```

However, this one doesn't return anything:

```
'/title="([0-9]+)"/sm'
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not taking into account the words around the number, try this:

```
$str = 'title="room 5 stars"';
preg_match_all('/title=".*(\d+).*"/', $str, $rate);

// The number is then in $rate[1][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to match the text before and after your number.
Try with : `/title=".*([0-9]+).*"/`

PS: you don't need *m* and *s* option

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a greedy match, it might give wrong results sometimes.

You can use `/title=".*?(\d+).*?"/` which is a lazy match and will search the least characters.

You can also try this free tool for regex matching: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Have you actually tested your regex? It will match the string, but not capture the number.

Comment: @ohaal no offense, but can you please tell me the mistake so I won't do it in the future. I edited the code for group matching.

Comment: I apologize for not going into detail in my previous comment, I was in a hurry. Removed the -1 as it seems you've fixed your answer. You had `/title=".*?(\d)*.*?"/` which did not capture the actual number. The reason for this is because `*` is equivalent to `{0,}`, and since the non-greedy match `.*?` had nothing to match against, all of the string would be matched against your last non-greedy `.*?` match.

Comment: @ohaal thanks for taking out time to mention the problem, much appreciated.